# Implement number of digits recursively in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I have this code to print the numbers based on the number of digits inputted (for example printNum1(2) will output 10-99, printNum1(3) will output 100-999, printNum1(4) will output 1000-9999) iteratively in python:

```
from time import time
def printNum1(n):
    start = time()
    y = 10 ** n
    x = y//10

    for i in range(x, y):
        print(i)
    print(f"For number {n}\nSol took: {time() - start} seconds")
printNum1(5)
```

I am trying to implement it recursively now for practice:

```
from time import time
from sys import setrecursionlimit
class PrintNumRec:
    setrecursionlimit(1000000000)
    def rec(self, x, y):
        if x == y:
            return
        else:
            print(x)
            return self.rec(x + 1, y)

    @staticmethod
    def init(n):
        start = time()

        y = 10 ** n
        x = y//10

        self = PrintNumRec()
        PrintNumRec.rec(self, x, y)
        print(f"For number {n}\nRecursive took: {time() - start} seconds")


PrintNumRec.init(10)
```

Originally I was getting:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I have seen this post [What is the maximum recursion depth in Python, and how to increase it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it)

From this post I tried to set the recursion limit higher but my program freezes for any number higher than 4 and I get this:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)
```

Is there any way to implement this recursively in Python or should I just stick to the iterative way?

Comment: The iterative method is going to be faster and easier. The range is easily calculated as `10 ** (n-1)` to `10 ** n - 1` so constantly calculating `x + 1` and checking `x == y` on each recursive call will be very slow.

Comment: Usually when you get a recursion error it means that you have an infinite recursion. Try tracking a variable by printing it to see if the number makes sense.

Comment: @YacineMahdid I went through the debugger and it works fine, no errors but doing this for 1000's numbers defeats the purpose.